# I've created 'Staff' table. In that table it has a self referencing key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
create table STAFF
(StaffID    TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
StaffName   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone       varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Gender      char(01),
DoB         date    NOT NULL,
Mentor      TINYINT,
Payment_ID  TINYINT NOT NULL,
constraint staff_pk primary key (StaffID),
constraint staff_fk foreign key (Payment_ID) references PAYMENT(Payment_ID),
constraint mentor_fk foreign key (Mentor) references staff(StaffID)
);
```

when it is executed it gives the following error.

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "mentor_fk". The conflict
>   occurred in database "F_T", table "dbo.STAFF", column 'StaffID'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Comment: The error says it came from an `INSERT`.  Are you sure you got it by running a `CREATE TABLE`?  Or did you leave out some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `staff` table first.  Then add the foreign key:

```
create table STAFF (
    StaffID    TINYINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    StaffName   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone       varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Gender      char(01),
    DoB         date    NOT NULL,
    Mentor      TINYINT,
    Payment_ID  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    constraint staff_pk primary key (StaffID),
    constraint staff_fk foreign key (Payment_ID) references PAYMENT(Payment_ID)
);

alter table staff
    add constraint mentor_fk foreign key (Mentor) references staff(StaffID);
```

Comment: I Appreciate your quick feedback.thanks a lot Mr.Gordon. But when I update the values as follow,
insert into STAFF
values ('Adeesha','077282018','M','1997-11-30','','5'),
('Kavitha','0772556899','F','1956-11-28','','4'),
('Patee Aiya','0775669844','M','1954-01-04','','3'),
('Chanuka','0772562984','M','1997-02-24','','2'),
('Umesha','0723328284','F','1997-11-26','','3');

It gives the error,
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "mentor_fk". The conflict occurred in database "F_T", table "dbo.STAFF", column 'StaffID'.

Comment: @ArunodaGunawardanaAdee . . . You should ask *another* question.  Include sample data, the table definitions, code, and error.  My best guess, though, is that the foreign key is referring to a row that doesn't exist.